# What is the most efficient way to save an Access 2007 database (or export tables) that will be opened on another computer?

Tags: database, ms-access, export

I have an access 2007 Database that consists of 3 tables each having 1 million, 2 million and 3 million records respectively. The size of the  .accdb (access databas file) is 
2,145,390,592 bytes (1.99 GB). I was able to zip the file (using winrar) down to 286,862 kb.

What I need to do is get the data in my 3 tables over to a client who is in another State and FTP is not an option so I will be placing the Data on a CD and mailing it to them through regular postal mail.

I do not want to use CSV files as I do not want them to have to do any importing of a CSV file or messing with field datatypes or anything. I just want the client to be able to open the data base or tables and see the data in access.

Am I going about this the right way by sending them the .accdb file or should I export and save each access table separately on to the CD and send that to them?

Comment: CSV is not a problem if you give the remote user also one script to create the database structure and to import the CSV files. The client only has to execute the script and everything gets done. This is the way I would do it in MySQL.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I will give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: What is the file size after a compact + repair. 2 million rows should not even be REMOTELY close to that size. Fastest way to copy data is to simply make a copy of the accdb file. However, before you do anything, get that file compacted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you are referring to by compact and repair but the .accdb file (which contained 3 tables with a total of about 6 millions records) was 1.99 gigs in size. When i compressed it using Winrar I got it down to 280MB which is what I burned on to the CD and sent over to the client. I'll look into the "compacting" and "repairing" you have mentioned. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original idea is perfect, burn the 280MB zip file on to a CD and let them unpack it at the other end, then as you say they can simply open Access and see all the data.

If they were using a different database to Access then it would be worth while exporting the individual files, but in this case it's not necessary and a waste of programming time.